# Spring boot with Spring Security with disabled csrf returns 403 forbidden on request with An expected CSRF token cannot be found in body

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

My spring boot application return 403 forbidden CSRF token cannot be found on all requests even with csrf disabled in filterChain
My filterChain Bean looks like this:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtTokenFilter(jwtTokenProvider), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
```

Filter class like this:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JwtTokenFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String bearerToken = ((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest).getHeader("Authorization");
        if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            bearerToken = bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        if (bearerToken != null && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(bearerToken)) {
            Authentication authentication = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(bearerToken);
            if (authentication != null) {
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

DEBUG Logs:

```
2023-04-14T11:38:34.554+03:00 DEBUG 13404 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.a.HttpWebHandlerAdapter          : [1cc1175d-1] HTTP POST "/auth/login"
2023-04-14T11:38:34.713+03:00 DEBUG 13404 --- [     parallel-1] o.s.w.s.s.DefaultWebSessionManager       : Created new WebSession.
2023-04-14T11:38:34.783+03:00 DEBUG 13404 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.a.HttpWebHandlerAdapter          : [1cc1175d-1] Completed 403 FORBIDDEN
```

[Request with headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sC4d.png)

I couldn't find a working answer in similar existing questions

**UPDATE:**
I created empty project just with filterChain and mock controller:

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class AController {
    @PostMapping(path = "/auth/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> login(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class AConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SecurityConfigurationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SecurityConfigurationApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Request:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/auth/login
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/17.0.5)
Accept-Encoding: br,deflate,gzip,x-gzip
```

Response:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/auth/login

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: text/plain
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
content-length: 38

An expected CSRF token cannot be found

Response code: 403 (Forbidden); Time: 154ms (154 ms); Content length: 38 bytes (38 B)
```

Comment: Show your request with headers. Show your Spring Security DEBUG logs.

Comment: FYI, Debug details do not mean Debug Logs.  What it means is what do you observe when you single step and what is the values of the variables.

Comment: Same problem mate. Version 6.1 problem